# Однофайловые компоненты vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как передать значение полученное с input v-model='searchQuery' из одного компонента в другой. Например есть два компонента vue таблица и поиск (фильтр по именам таблицы) как из поиска передать значение v-model='searchQuery' в таблицу. Примерный код

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <NewSearch></NewSearch>
    <NewTable></NewTable>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
  import Search from './components/Search.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      NewTable: Hello,
      NewSearch: Search
    }
  }
</script>

// Search.vue

<template>
  <div class="search-block">
  <input id="input-search" type="text" placeholder="Search users" v-model="searchQuery">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'searchBlock',

  data: function() {
  return {
   searchQuery: ''
  }
 }
}
</script>

// Table (hello)

<template>
 <div class="container">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th v-for='column in columns' v-on:click='sortTable(column)'>
     {{ column }}
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr v-for='row in filteredUsers'>
    <td v-for="column in columns">{{row[column]}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
</template>

<script>

export default {
 name: 'hello',
  data: function() {
    return {
   rows: [
    { name: 'John', email: "john@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' },
    { name: 'Jane', email: "jane@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' },
    { name: 'Paul', email: "paul@gmail.com", root: 'Admin' },
    { name: 'Kate', email: "kate@gmail.com", root: 'Admin' },
    { name: 'Amanda', email: "amanda@gmail.com", root: 'User' },
    { name: 'Steve', email: "steve@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' },
    { name: 'Keith', email: "keith@gmail.com", root: 'User' },
    { name: 'Don', email: "don@gmail.com", root: 'Admin' },
    { name: 'Susan', email: "susan@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' }
   ]
    }
 }
 computed: {
  filteredUsers: function() {
   return this.rows.filter(function(user) {
    return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1;
   }.bind(this));
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить вот это:

```
<input id="input-search" type="text" placeholder="Search users" v-model="searchQuery">
```

на:

```
<input id="input-search" type="text" placeholder="Search users" @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)">
```

В родителе:

```
<NewSearch @input="searchQuery = arguments[0]"></NewSearch>
<NewTable :searchQuery="searchQuery"></NewTable>
```

Не забыть добавить searchQuery в data родителя и в пропсы NewTable.